# Consulta Eloquent - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola estoy haciendo una consulta de esta forma

```html
 $publicaciones = Publicacion::with(['user','comentarios.user','fotos'])
                      ->whereHas('fotos')
            ->wherein('categoria_id',$listaCategorias)
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->paginate(10);
```

todo bien, pues me carga todos los comentarios, pero necesito solo cargar maximo 5 comentarios por publicación si es que tiene.

Lo intente de esta manera

```html
 $publicaciones = Publicacion::with(['user','categoria','comentarios' =>function($comentario) {

       return  $comentario->with('user')
                   ->orderBy('id','desc')
                   ->take(5);
    }])
                 ->whereHas('fotos')
            ->wherein('categoria_id',$listaCategorias)
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->paginate(10);
```

pero pues no funciona ya que lo que hace eso es de 10 publicaciones por ejmplo.

solo me carga los primeros 4 comentarios de la primer publicación ya las demás publicaciones no cargan sus comentarios, aunque se que tiene.

En resumen "Cómo hacerle para que me muestre 5 comentarios como Maximo de cada publicación en caso de tener "

Comment: deberias usar el limit? al final de la consulta. ->limit(5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que intentas hacer es básicamente limitar los resultados únicamente en la relación que está cargada por merio de Eager Loading.

Esto **NO** es posible de forma predeterminada por Laravel, y siempre ha habido una amplia discusión al respecto desde hace ya varios años.

El problema para que esto funcione es que se necesitarían hacer varias consultas y perdería su esencia el Eager Loading, que lo que pretende es precisamente eso: evitar incrementar el número de consultas a la base de datos.

Soluciones:

- Hacer las consultas manuales.
- Limitar los resultados en las colecciones obtenidas (ver los métodos que se pueden aplicar a las colecciones, en la documentación).
- Utilizar un paquete como este, que permite limitar las consultas con Eager Loading: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit